# Jquery - Form submit gives a dropdown selected value, How to set associated html using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form, which submits a retains the dropdown value previously selected, initially, before submitting the form, on selecting any option in dropdown used to display or hide some htmls elements, using jquery, now the problem is how to use jquery on finding the selected value after form submit to control the other html element like it does before submit.

The code below is when I manually change the value in dropdown:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#representative').change(function(){
        var rep = $('#representative').val();
        if(rep == 'Golfer'){
            golfer();
        } else if (rep == 'Bussiness') {
            bussiness();
        } else {
            def();
        }
    });
});
```

I am looking for the way If after submitting the form when I get any preselected value in the dropdown, I must get either the function bussiness(); to executed or function golfer(); should be executed.

Comment: Some code would be useful. What have you tried and how have you implemented this?

Comment: I couldn't help but notice your lack of code. It runs deep. Share your code with me.

Comment: @AlexMorrise Find the updated code

Comment: Is the form submission handled through ajax? or standard form submission processing? (page reload)

Comment: standard form submission using PHP in backend

Comment: Then everything on the clientside is lost when the page reloads ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is move your variable check outside of the scope, and get the selected value.

```
var selectedRep = $('#representative').val();
if(selectedRep == 'Golfer'){
    golfer();
}else if(selectedRep == 'Bussiness'){
    bussiness();
}else{
    def();
}
```

Simply place that inside of your `$(document).ready({ // code here });` function, and it will evaluate when the page loads.

Comment: Excellent...... It worked.... It was too easy.. Silly question may b from my end.... Thanks Again.....